# Query specific word from the Orientdb table

Tags: java, orientdb3.0

I am using Orientdb-3.0.27.

I have a table that contains different columns and I have to fetch the columns and rows from that table based on any specific word.

For example, in the following table, I have to fetch all the rows and columns which contain the word **data**. ignoring the case.

Also, there will be more columns and rows which may contain the word **data**.

[image]

WHAT will be the suitable query for fetching all those columns as well as rows which will contain this word.

I have used the Query:-

```
select * from `DB_Table_Name` where ANY() Like '%data%';
```

But here ANY() is not working.

I have to search on the basis of words or letters, not on the basis of columns.

For example, I want to get all the rows and columns containing word demo or data.

Let's asume that we dont have the knowledge of existing Column name.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM DB_Table_Name WHERE user_Name CONTAINS 'data' OR user_Description CONTAINS 'data';"`

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem did you have with it?

Comment: I have to query all the columns, It is not specific that have to query from user_Name or user_Description. 


I have used this query:- 




```select * from `DB_Table_Name` where ANY() Like '%data%'; ```

But ANY() is not working

Comment: @DevilsHnd Can you suggest some other way to query it. as none of the above query is working. I have also modified the question

Comment: @kislaykashyap - please refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343087/819866